# Limiting Image Downloads to My Website

Tags: nginx

I have a website that automatically generates thumbnails using a proxy to Thumbor. It works by accepting an image address at the end of the URL. For example, to make a 30x30 image:

```
http://images.mydomain.com/unsafe/30x30/http://example.com/logo.png
http://images.mydomain.com/unsafe/30x30/http://google.com/logo.png
```

Right now anyone could generate new thumbnails easily since it's open. Thumbor allows me to sign requests but it's a pain with my setup. I'm wondering if Nginx provides a way to do it so only images will load if they are loaded from within my website.

Here is my config:

```
    upstream thumbor {
            server 127.0.0.1:8000;
            server 127.0.0.1:8001;
            server 127.0.0.1:8002;
            server 127.0.0.1:8003;
    }

    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2;
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

            server_name images.example.com;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://thumbor;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Yes - search for "Nginx hotlink protection". Someone might answer the question more fully for you, but it's pretty simple.

Comment: Why don't you just pregenerate the thumbnails in your application?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I could, but it's a lot of work. I'd like to use HTML srcset so I can have different images for different resolutions. I'm using Ghost, so I can't generate thumbnails in code either, everything has to be done in the WYSIWYG editor.